# Time series with multiple stores multiple products

Tags: r, time-series

I have a 300 stores and 20000 products in my data set and I want to predict next 3 months sales forecast for each outlet each product level. And my data frame looks like this (sample) like this data frame I m taking from SQL Server 2016

```
  Date    outlet produ     price
2019-Jan    A     W          10
2019-Feb    A     R          20
2019-Feb    A     W          15
2019-Jan    B     W          30
2019-Jan    B     F          40
2019-Feb    B     W          40
```

what I tried is get the single product observation entire time series and set to model and get the output

```
##getthe data set like this

outlet <-c('A','A','B','B')
produ  <-c('W','R','W','F')
price  <-c(10,20,30,40)
df <- data.frame(outlet,produ,price)

##tried to get single product 
dpSingle <- dplyr::filter(df,df$produ  == 'W')
data.ts=ts(Quntity, start=c(year,month), frequency=12)
fit_arima <- auto.arima(data.ts,d=1,D=1,stepwise =  FALSE
                    ,approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE) 
fcast<-forecast(fit_arima,h=24)
autoplot(fcast) + ggtitle("Forecasted for next 24 months")+ 
ylab("quntity")+xlab("Time in days")
print((exp(fcast$mean )))
```

but what i want is loop through a data frame and identify outlet first and then product and get particulars observations with features and pass to my time series model and get predictions individually for each outlet each product.